# Argument capturing on the insides of closures in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am trying to test a method that does an invocation with a closure, something like this:

```
def foo(Long param) {
    AnObject.doSomething {
       bar(param)
    }
}
```

And I want to test that `doSomething` is called with a closure that calls `bar` with the expected value inside.

I'm able to test properly the `doSomething` invocation by creating a spy and doing

```
when:
    service.foo(1L)
then:
    1 * AnObject.doSomething{_}
```

However, I cannot seem to find a way to perform assertions on the contents of the closure.

What's the appropriate way to assert that inside the closure `bar` gets called with 1L?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, I think you would need to spy on the class providing the bar method. This is a bit contrived because the test is supplying the closure, but I think it is something like this:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class Bar {
    void bar(def param) {
        println param
    }
}

class DoSomethingTestSpec extends Specification {

    class AnObject {

        void doSomething(Closure c) {

            def param = 1L

            c.call(param)
        }
    }

    def "test AnObject doSomething calls the closure"() {

        given:
        def closure = { def p ->
            Bar.bar(p)
        }

        and:
        GroovySpy(Bar, global:true)

        and:
        AnObject anObject = new AnObject()

        when:
        anObject.doSomething(closure)

        then:
        1 * Bar.bar(_) >> { args ->
            assert args[0] == 1L
        }
    }
}
```